# Django model F expression divide by zero error when calculating dynamic running total and average

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django 3.2

I am dynamically calculating field values for an item that can be rated.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
self.ratings_count = F('ratings_count') + 1
self.ratings_total = F('ratings_total') + rating_value
self.ratings_average =  F('ratings_total') / F('ratings_count')  
self.last_rated = timezone.now()
self.save()  # Divide by zero error here (no records exist in Db)
```

I could trivially get around this by not using F fields (as a kludge - with attendant race conditions). My question is - how do I implement the desired behaviour, whilst using F expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st solution is to save the value of `ratings_count` & `ratings_total` before using it in the division operation, like that:

```py
self.ratings_count = F('ratings_count') + 1
self.ratings_total = F('ratings_total') + rating_value

self.save(update_fields=['self.ratings_total', 'self.ratings_count']) # try to remove `self` if there are a problme

self.ratings_average =  F('ratings_total') / F('ratings_count')  
self.last_rated = timezone.now()

self.save(update_fields=['ratings_average', 'last_rated'])
```

the 2nd solution is:

```py
self.ratings_count = F('ratings_count') + 1
self.ratings_total = F('ratings_total') + rating_value

if self.ratings_count == 0 and self.ratings_total == 0:
    self.ratings_average = rating_value
else:
    self.ratings_average = (F('ratings_total') + rating_value) / (F('self.ratings_count')+1)

self.last_rated = timezone.now()

self.save()
```

Comment: I mean they are different types: `type(self.ratings_total)
<class 'django.db.models.expressions.CombinedExpression'>` unless the object is coerced to a boolean type. I just run it, and the boolean comparison always returns false - even when no records (ratings) in db.

Comment: The expression `if self.ratings_count == 0 and self.ratings_total == 0:` always evaluates as `False`. Are you sure this check is necessary?

Comment: Every object must start its life cycle with an initial value = 0 in `ratings_count` and the `ratings_total`  and if the `if` condition return `False` this means this object already have a rating value!
 
so, set default=0 in `ratings_count`  & `ratings_total` fields and try to create another object and test on it